# PDE inequalities to show a gradient is integrable

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations

I'm having trouble understanding the two inequalities in [page 9](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2108.08942.pdf), quoted below.

> From the fact that $u\in C^{0,\alpha}(M)$, apply $W^{2,p}$ estimate followed by Sobolev embedding onto $w_r(x)$, where $r>0$ fixed, in a (conic) annulus $A(1)$ around $p$, we have
> $$|\nabla u|_{C^0(A(r))}\leq |\nabla\nabla u|_{L^p(A(r))}\leq Cr^{\alpha-1}.$$
> $|\nabla u|$ is therefore integrable on $\partial M$ and also on $M$.

Unless I missed it, I don't think the author defines $w_r(x)$, which is one minor area of confusion. In any case, we're estimating on the boundary of $M$, and $\dim\partial M=2$. Note that we can't immediately get an $L^1$ bound on $\nabla u$ by GNS since
$$|\nabla u|_{L^1}\leq |\nabla\nabla u|_{L^p}\implies 1=\frac{2p}{2-p}\implies p=2/3.$$

I'm not sure what the author means by "apply $W^{2,p}$ estimate followed by Sobolev embedding", which I assume gives the first inequality. I record a few thoughts below. I assume the domains are $A(r)$, which I will omit from the notation.

1. We can use GNS inequality for $1\leq p<2$, to relate $\nabla u$ to its derviative. For $n=2$, we get
   $$|\nabla u|_{L^{\frac{2p}{2-p}}}\leq |\nabla\nabla u|_{L^p}.$$
   I am unsure how to proceed from here. I definitely don't think it's true that

$$|\nabla u|_{C^0}\leq C|u|_{L^\frac{2p}{2-p}}.$$

2. We want to apply one of the following argument to $v=\nabla u$, and this is possible if $u\in W^{3,2}$. But $u\in W^{3,p}$ on the interior (see [Lemma 1.1, page 3](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2108.08942.pdf)), not boundary, of $M$. By the general [Sobolev inequalities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_space#Sobolev_embeddings), for $n=2$, we know that $v\in W^{2,p}$ with $p=2,3,4,...$, then for any $\alpha\in (0,1)$, we have
   $$|v|_{C^{0,\alpha}}\leq C|v|_{W^{2,i}}.$$
   Alternatively, for $1\leq p< 2$, for $\alpha=2-2/p$, we get
   $$|v|_{C^{0,\alpha}}\leq C|v|_{W^{2,p}}.$$
   Alternatively, for $p>2$ not an integer, we have for $\alpha=1-2/p$,
   $$|v|_{C^{0,\alpha}}\leq C|v|_{W^{2,p}}.$$

For the second inequality, I'm assuming this comes from the domain being a conic annulus, and somehow $u\in C^{0,\alpha}$ should enter. But I'm not clear how this is done.

Comment: The author defines $w_r(x) = u(rx)-u(x)$ on page $10$, after the end of the proof. Not sure if it is the same function used in page $9$ though

Comment: Hm I see, thanks for pointing that out. I wonder if the second estimate is a kind of Schauder estimate on $A(r)$ then.