# Schauder estimates on a punctured disk.

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, general-relativity

The following is related to my previous question [1], which I think can be resolved if this question is resolved. Is it true for $u\in C^{1,\alpha}(B-p)$ where $B=B_p(r)$ a function satisfying the spacetime Laplacian $\Delta u+K|\nabla u|=0,$
that the following estimate holds,
$$r^2|\nabla\nabla u|\leq C r^{1+\alpha}?$$
Here, $K$ is the trace of some prescribed symmetric $(0,2)$ tensor $k$. For simplicity, let us assume $K=0$, so that $u$ is harmonic. Classical Schauder estimates from Gilbarg-Trudinger tell us that the following bound holds, $$r^2|\nabla\nabla u|\leq C |u|_{C^0(B-p)}.$$
Does it follow that for harmonic $u$, we have $|u|_{0;B-p}\leq C r^{1+\alpha}$?

**References:**
[1]: [PDE inequalities to show a gradient is integrable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4660598/pde-inequalities-to-show-a-gradient-is-integrable)

Comment: Do you have boundary conditions? Without then you cannot hope for an inequality of the form $\vert u \vert_{0,B\setminus \{p\}} \leqslant \text{ “something” }$  since $u+M$ also satisfies the PDE for all $M\in \mathbb R$

Comment: I see, thank you for the remark. Depending on $p$, we have that either $u=0, u=1$, or $\partial_\nu u=0$. I will check to confirm in detail later and update the body.